# web scraping script stops if internet connection interrupted

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I have written web scraping script using python selenium web driver it is working fine but the problem is data is too large so when ever internet connection interrupted for some second my script will stop execution so again i have to start from the beginning.
please help me or guide me some other solution using scrapy framework

**Working Code:**

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import MySQLdb

# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                     user="root", # your username
                     passwd="", # your password
                     db="test") # name of the data base

url = "http://xlnindia.gov.in/frm_G_Cold_S_Query.aspx"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)

time.sleep(5)
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

states = [ x["value"] for x in soup.find("td", bgcolor="#ffe0c0").find_all("option") ]

for state in states:

    cur_state = browser.find_element_by_id("ddldistrict")
    cur_state.send_keys(state)

    html = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

    districts = [ x["value"] for x in soup.find("td", bgcolor="#ffe0c0").find_next_sibling().find_all("option") ]
    districts = districts[1:]

    for dist in districts:

        district = browser.find_element_by_id("ddldistrict")
        district.send_keys(dist)

        html = browser.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
        
        talukas = [ x["value"] for x in soup.find("td", bgcolor="#ffe0c0").find_next_sibling().find_all("option") ]
        talukas = talukas[1:]

        for taluka in talukas:

            category = browser.find_element_by_id("ddltaluka")
            category.send_keys(taluka)

            button = browser.find_element_by_id("btnSearch")
            button.click()

            time.sleep(10)
            browser.save_screenshot(browser.title + ".JPEG")
            html = browser.page_source
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
            table = soup.find(id="dgDisplay")
            if table:
                #print("found")
                cursor=db.cursor()
                for row in table.findAll("tr")[1:]:
                    cells = row.findAll("td")
                    name = cells[0].find(text=True)
                    city = cells[1].find(text=True)
                    licence = cells[2].find(text=True)
                    owner = cells[3].find(text=True)
                    print("Name:"+name+"city:"+city+"licence:"+licence+"owner:"+owner)
                    try:
                       cursor.execute ("INSERT INTO distributors (name, city, licence, owner) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);", (name, city, licence, owner))
                    except (MySQLdb.Error, MySQLdb.Warning) as e:
                        print(e)
                db.commit()        
            #else:  
            #    print("not found")
db.close()                
browser.close()
browser.quit()
```

Comment: An example of the exact exception, with stack trace, would be very helpful.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Normally driver throws exception immediately if you are not setting the implicitly timeout when it finds an element. So if the page is getting loaded slowly also handled by this way and also, find element will wait even the interrupted. You can add following timeout after launching the browser and try, It may help you.

```
driver.implicitly_wait(30);
```

Comment: And insert another try/except block at the top of the for-loop to catch TimeoutExceptions. This prevents the program from exiting. And perhaps schedule a retry after a suitable pause within the except part of the block.